# How to write and read nested integer lists to csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, export-to-csv

I have a more-dimensional matrix as data input for a python model. For this, I am using nested lists that are saved in a different model but also using python. My questions are how to correctly save these lists as csv files + how to import them correctly.

The nested lists look like this:

```
test = [[[3, 16], [10, 12]], [[4, 2], [14, 6]]]
```

From reading other examples, I tried saving them using this code:

```py
# Write CSV file
kwargs = {'newline': ''}
mode = 'w'
if sys.version_info < (3, 0):
    kwargs.pop('newline', None)
    mode = 'wb'

with open('../data/test.csv', mode, **kwargs) as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerows(test)
```

which gives an output like this:

```
"[3, 16]","[10, 12]"
"[4, 2]","[14, 6]"
```

Looking at the format, I ask myself if this is really the right way to write the file for more dimensional lists.
**=> Q1: What is the right way to write nested lists?**

Reading the file using

```py
# Read CSV file
kwargs = {'newline': ''}
mode = 'r'
if sys.version_info < (3, 0):
    kwargs.pop('newline', None)
    mode = 'rb'
with open('../data/test.csv', mode, **kwargs) as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp, delimiter=',')
    data_read = [row for row in reader]
```

has the output

```
[['[3, 16]', '[10, 12]'], ['[4, 2]', '[14, 6]']]
```

The differences in formats bring me to the second question:
**=> Q2: How to get integers back when reading the file?**

I believe this problem cannot be that difficult, but I just started working with python so I'm not sure how to adjust the code. Hence, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: JSON would probably be better suited for that kind of data.

Comment: Do you plan to use the saved CSV files with other (non-Python) software? If not, `pickle` the lists.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't really have anything to do with Python. The CSV format does not support nested data structures (e.g., lists within lists). One solution is to use an encoding which does; e.g., JSON. Alternatively, if the data will only be read by a Python program you could use python's `pickle` module to efficiently encode/decode the object.

Note: You could define your own CSV meta encoding for lists within a list. But then you have to figure out a scheme for doing so and write a decoder for whatever language will need to read the serialized data. Far easier to use JSON, protobufs, or another appropriate encoding.

Answer (score -1):

I have previously made a script that should fix some of your problems.

https://github.com/Yolo-gamer/CDM

In my code there are two ways my script saves data.

1. Normal (as string)
2. Data (saves with data types)

All that is needed is the cdm.py file to be in the same folder as your script then  use `import cdm`

For help type help(cdm) and the code should give you all the information you need.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.